# sql error on script execution. try deleting repository before creating repository

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-sql-developer

I want to migrate my mysql databse to oracle.
I have followed the migration demo from this url http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/connect-step-mysql-1946352.html

but I got this message when try to associate migration repository

`sql error on script execution. try deleting repository before creating repository`

I am using 
**Oracle Sql Developer v 4.1.1.19**
**Oracle express edition 11g releas 2**

see the picture bellow what I have tried step by step

step1: Creating a user named **migration_repo**

[image]

step 2: Creating connection named **migration_repo** using **migration_repo** user
[image]

step3: try to associate migration repository
[image]

step4: executing the command
[image]

but after few seconds I got this error message.
[image]

Now. how can I solve this? what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the video tutorial missed a grant, the correct command is the following:

```
GRANT 
    CONNECT, 
    RESOURCE, 
    CREATE SESSION, 
    CREATE VIEW, 
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW 
TO migration_repo 
IDENTIFIED BY migration_repo;
```

The database must also have the `USERS` tablespace.
I found the previous information in [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3558113?start=0&tstart=0).

Answer (score 0):

Allocating unlimited table space quotas for this user helped me.

For example:

```
CREATE USER MIGRATION_REPO IDENTIFIED BY migration_repo
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS 
quota unlimited on USERS 
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP;
```

Answer (score -4):

alter user mwrep
  quota unlimited on users;

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site and thanks for your contribution. Could you elaborate what you think the problem is and how your code is supposed to solve it? As it stands now it's just a piece of code without explanation and I wouldn't suggest anybody to run random code found on the internet without explaining what it's supposed to do.